# FASM win 64: program working with floating point operands

Tags: performance, assembly, floating-point, x86-64, win64

I have a university task to write a simple program in FASM win64 Assembler, which should calculate the following  expression:

> [image: task]
>
> Where:
>
> - S - result;
> - A - constant 20 020 426;
> - B - some variable
>
> The result of the program should be the message: "S is less/more than A"
>
> We now work with float point numbers

I just can't understand how to divide and than subtract...

````
entry Start
include 'win64a.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable

  A dd 20022604;
  B dd 1;
  mem1 dd 0
  log2 dd 1.1443;
  NULL = 0
  
  mes1 db 'S is greater than A', 0dh, 0ah, 0
  mes1Len = $ - mes1
  mes2 db 'S is less or equal to A', 0dh, 0ah, 0
  mes2Len = $ - mes2
  
  resStr db 'Result: %d', 0
  
  contitle db 'Results', 0
  hStdIn dd 0
  hStdOut dd 0
  chrsRead dd 0
  chrsWritten dd 0
  STD_INP_HNDL  dd -10
  STD_OUTP_HNDL dd -11

section '.bss' readable writeable 
  readBuf db ?

section '.idata' import data readable
    library kernel,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
      msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
    
    import kernel,\
      SetConsoleTitleA, 'SetConsoleTitleA',\
      GetStdHandle, 'GetStdHandle',\
      WriteConsoleA, 'WriteConsoleA',\
      ReadConsoleA, 'ReadConsoleA',\
      ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
    
    import msvcrt,\
      puts,'puts',\
      scanf,'scanf',\
      printf,'printf',\ 
      exit,'exit',\
      getch, '_getch'


section '.code' code readable executable
Start:
    mov edx, 0
    mov eax, [A]
    mov ebx, 4
    
    div ebx 
    mov [mem1], edx

    mov edi, [log2];
    
    sub eax, edi;
    
    mov ebx, [B]
    
    mul ebx
    
    mov ebx, A
    
    cmp eax, ebx
    jg greater
    

    invoke GetStdHandle, [STD_OUTP_HNDL]
    mov [hStdOut], eax

    invoke GetStdHandle, [STD_INP_HNDL]
    mov [hStdIn], eax

    invoke WriteConsoleA, [hStdOut], mes2, mes2Len, chrsWritten, 0
    invoke ReadConsoleA, [hStdIn], readBuf, 1, chrsRead, 0

    jmp exit

greater:
    invoke GetStdHandle, [STD_OUTP_HNDL]
    mov [hStdOut], eax

    invoke GetStdHandle, [STD_INP_HNDL]
    mov [hStdIn], eax

    invoke WriteConsoleA, [hStdOut], mes1, mes1Len, chrsWritten, 0
    invoke ReadConsoleA, [hStdIn], readBuf, 1, chrsRead, 0
    



Exit:
  invoke ReadConsoleA, [hStdIn], readBuf, 1, chrsRead, 0
  invoke ExitProcess, 0 ``` 

What is the mistake?
````

Comment: Floating point uses different registers and instructions.  asm doesn't have "types", in the same that `mul` is always the same binary integer operation, even if you use it on a floating-point bit-pattern.  Use `mulss xmm0, xmm1` for scalar `float` multiply, and `movss xmm0, [log2]` for loading a float.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mulss.  And look at C compiler output as an example, like on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Why is this tagged [performance]?  None of this seems efficient.  Like using `div` to divide by a constant 4, instead of an integer right shift.  (If you wanted to use floating-point for that part, too, you'd need to write `A dd 20022604.0` to make it a float, not integer.  But the division by 4 happens to be exact for that constant `A`.)  BTW, I've never seen `:` used in an expression to indicate division.  If they wanted division, I'd expect something like `A/4 - log_2 e`

Comment: I wonder if they're intending you to use x87 math here, since it has `FLDL2E` to load log2(e) as a constant.  But if you're actually using 64-bit code with single-precision (`dd`) floats, then SSE for scalar math would be the normal thing, so yeah you'd either just hard-code a constant (with enough decimal digits to get the nearest float to l2(e)), or you'd call a `log` function (like `ln(e) / ln(2)`, aka `1/ln(2)`) or implement `log2` yourself, e.g. with FP exponent and mantissa and a polynomial approximation over the [1-1.999] mantissa range.... so probably not that.